# How to find the cause of slow query mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb

My mongoDB collection (statistics) has 17 million documents.

I tried **QUERY 1** :

```
db.statistics.find({
"updated_at": {$lt: ISODate("2018-08-21 01:00:00"),  $gte: ISODate("2018-08-21 00:00:00")}
});
```

Returned : 534 documents.
Time : 170 seconds.

After then, I tried **QUERY 2** :

```
db.statistics.find({
"updated_at": {$lt: ISODate("2018-08-21 01:00:00")}
});
```

Returned : 16 million documents.
Time : 0.065 second .

I tried explain on that.

Result **QUERY 1** :

```
{
    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
    "filter" : {
        "$and" : [
            {
            "updated_at" : {
                "$lt" : ISODate("2018-08-21T08:00:00.000+07:00")
            }
        },
            {
            "updated_at" : {
                "$gte" : ISODate("2018-08-21T07:00:00.000+07:00")
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    "nReturned" : 534,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 131587,
    "works" : 17784357,
    "advanced" : 534,
    "needTime" : 17783822,
    "needYield" : 0,
    "saveState" : 139020,
    "restoreState" : 139020,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "direction" : "forward",
    "docsExamined" : 17784355
}
```

Result  **QUERY 2** :

```
{
    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
    "filter" : {
        "updated_at" : {
            "$lt" : ISODate("2018-08-21T08:00:00.000+07:00")
        }
    },
    "nReturned" : 16676319,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 135988,
    "works" : 17784357,
    "advanced" : 16676319,
    "needTime" : 1108037,
    "needYield" : 0,
    "saveState" : 139089,
    "restoreState" : 139089,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "direction" : "forward",
    "docsExamined" : 17784355
}
```

**QUERY 2** very fast and **QUERY 1** very slow.

How to find where is the cause of that?

Comment: Guessing from far away this sounds like a caching thing. Can you reproduce the same behavior over and over again? I have a feeling for the first query, MongoDB loaded lots of data from a slow disk into memory and for the second query this cached data was used.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `Query 1` & `Query 2` in that order, a likely cause was that `Query 1` took longer since it needs to load all the collection's data into RAM. Now when `Query 2` runs, the whole collection is already in RAM.

Basically you have a cold cache for `Query 1`, and you have a warm cache for `Query 2`. If you reverse the order of execution, you should find that `Query 1` will be fast.

This is because both explain output show two very similar plans:

- Both of them show `COLLSCAN` stage, which means that MongoDB must load the whole collection into RAM, examine *all* 17,784,355 documents one by one, and return the requested documents.
- Both queries examined the same number of documents (17,784,355)
- Both show almost identical `executionTimeMillisEstimate`

What you want to do is to eliminate any `COLLSCAN` in your explain output. Ideally you'd like to see `IXSCAN` instead.

For example, if you create an index on the collection based on your query:

```
db.statistics.createIndex({updated_at: 1})
```

the index will significantly speed up the two queries you have.

More resources that you might find useful:

- [db.collection.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html)
- [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/index.html)

Comment: `If you reverse the order of execution, you should find that Query 1 will be fast.` I tried, but it still not change. I think problem not in cache. Add Index is good solution But in my case, I cant add index because it can affect to other query

Comment: Are you saying that query 1 is _always slow_ and query 2 is _always fast_ no matter what? The explain results show almost identical output, and yet you're seeing one query is __2600 times__ faster than the other?

Comment: Yes, query 1 is always slow. query 2 always fast

Comment: This is interesting. Could you run both queries at least 10 times (query 1 at least 10 times, query 2 at least 10 times), and post the total time, average time, standard deviation of the times, and run them in order of query 1 then query 2, and also query 2 then query 1?

Answer (score 0):

in this case you use ***ls*** and ***gt*** for **query 1** That takes itself  implicit mongoDb filtering using two parameters for whole data collection ( which has millions of records) thus giving it a more delay than just using ***lt***. When using ***lt*** , it doesn't want to filter using both parameters just the values which are below you required parameter. that's why it behaves like that.

to mitigate this longer querying time, you can use index in mongoDb to specifically identify which fields should it query first. ( kind of like ObjectIds which has already indexed at the beginning of the document creation)